# Install VS 2008 Express fails

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, 64-bit, installation

I'm trying to install VS 2008 Express on a 64 bit Win 7 machine that has VS 2010 Pro installed already.   Early in the install I get an error to wit:  "Setup.exe has stopped working. ... windows will close the program".   Further in a background window it says: "Setup could not install the following compenent:   Runtime Pre-requisites".

This error happens whether I'm installing 2008 express from the web setup or 2008 Pro from the MSDN CD.

A search pointed me to Control Panel | Turn Windows Features on or off | Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1.   I tried enabling and disabling this with no difference.  Setup still failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What pre-requisite is failing? Did you try to download that as a stand alone installer and install it?

Comment: You will need to check the log file that is created by the installer. It probably exists in `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp`. You are looking for an error that looks like `Visual C++ Runtime Pre-requisites: Cannot access file: C:\WINDOWS\wcu\vcredist_x86.exe`, or something similar.

Comment: Hm, some months ago, have seen similar error. After googling, found the source - some update, which conflicts with installer. I'm not sure, what it was... may be Silverlight, or some VS service pack's. Try to uninstall tnem, one-by-ony and run VS2008 setup again?

Comment: Answer to Oded & J.W.R.  I don't know.  The error just says as above: Setup.exe has stopped working...   I can't find a log file in c:\users\<myname>\appdata.   I looked for \*.log, \*vs\*, \*2008\*.   Nada.   Any other ideas?